# how can i make preview.php file using database id

Tags: php

i working on covers website and when i looking around i found website have button it called preview cover

then i check it and found if some one click on preview cover it give him that

example pic

1 : http://s23.postimg.org/5skae5gvt/Capture.png

2 : http://s16.postimg.org/62wrpfbyd/Capture1.png

how can i made preview file and using database id to get pic ?

the website for live preview fabcovers.com/cover-1083-tolerance-education-quotes.html

Thanks

Comment: what you mean than 'database id' in 'how can i made preview file and using database id to get pic ?'

Comment: that mena i have database then i can get id , caption , location of file by using id pic in database that is all

Comment: you can have that but you should create a table in database with some fields like id pic_name pic_url so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the URL in the DB, and set a custom cover like `$cover` for example. Then when the user clicks on preview you can add an ID of the header in the URL, get the URL from the DB and place it in `$cover`.

Comment: i would like to coding preview.php file that hover image like this file http://www.fabcovers.com/preview.php

Comment: You can set a:hover in your css for example.

Comment: can you tell me how plz ?

Comment: In your css file you can set the a:hover, or inline style if you prefer so. You can read this for further info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: this is no`t help can u plz give me more info

Comment: How is that no help? If you read that you'll get all the info you need. I'm not going to code the piece for you.